# Programmatically create an http file in new http folder in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, http, dynamic

I need to dynamically create a http file specific to each desktop app user so that I can redirect him/her to the created url when on a button is clicked in the app. So it has to be http, not ftp.

The file's folder also needs to be created on the fly.

I started by trying to create/upload a file into an existing http folder.

Attempt [1] System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'

```
  Dim client As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
  client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
  client.UploadFile("httpWwwDomainDotCom/someFolder/destinationFile.txt", 
    "c:\users\someUser\desktop\sourceFile.txt")      
  client.Dispose()
```

Attempt [2]
The following code gives me a success message but no file is being created!

```
 Try
     Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = 
DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("httpWwwDomainDotCom/someFolder/destinationFile.txt"), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)

     request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
     request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Post

     Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("c:\users\someUser\desktop\sourceFile.txt")

     Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
     stream.Write(file, 0, file.Length)

     stream.Close()
     stream.Dispose()

     MsgBox("Http uploading succeeded!")

  Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox("Http uploading failed!")
  End Try
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What does your web side script look like that handles this?

Comment: That will be som php code in the created html file to do some stuff I'd like once the user landed op the page. That part is working properly..

Comment: Well, you can't just upload a file to a server via HTTP, otherwise people could flood existing websites... You need a PHP file that handles what you have uploaded and stores it appropriately.

Comment: So apparently,, no way to upload files on http path not even with credentials so that only the owner of the server can do it. 
I guess, I will have to do what you said: upload on ftp, since I can do that with credentials in code, then use php to copy the uploaded file to the http path. Thx @Jaxi

Comment: Just create a PHP file, called for example "uploadfile.php", pass along credentials to check, file location and file contents, then php can write to that location with the contents and report back success :)

Comment: I ended up doing the following:
- upload the file to ftp folder on server 
- trigger a web page with php code in it to copy the uploaded file to http folder 

That php page, I could call from my desktop application in the background using something like: 
[CODE]
Dim phpFile As String = "http://someDomain/copy.php"
Dim response As WebResponse
Dim request As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(phpFile)
response = request.GetResponse()
[END CODE] 
Can't believe one cannot just upload files to an http address using credentials!!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

- upload the file to ftp folder
- trigger a web page with php code in it to copy the uploaded file to http folder

That php page, I could call from my desktop application in the background with this code:

```
Dim phpFile As String = "http://someDomain/copy.php" 
Dim response As WebResponse
Dim request As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(phpFile)
response = request.GetResponse()
```

Can't believe one cannot just upload files to an http address using credentials!!